# ListView not scroll completely

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I am facing a problem. There are 7 items in a list and only 3 are visible on screen. When I scroll down the listview scrolls until the third item but it doesn't go any further. When I go up again and then try to scroll down again it works fine. Below is my layout file :

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_list"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="List Items"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_background" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/relatedList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="15.0sp"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/relatedList"
         android:nextFocusUp="@id/relatedList"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="none"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: why are you adding android:nextFocusDown="@id/relatedList"
         android:nextFocusUp="@id/relatedList" these lines in this ?

Comment: @RajanBhavsar it was added by mistake. now i checked after removing these line. but no works.

Comment: @RajanBhavsar i have changed my ListView by  GridView With one column its works fine for me...but i want to know what is the problem in my listview.

Comment: Let me try with your layout

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing the line

```
android:layout_height="0dip"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: That is not the Issue dear friend as he was used the weight to work on that LinearLayout.